# Comparing EditTexts says they're not equal when they are

Tags: java, android

I take the text from the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Contraseña"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editNombre" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ConfirmPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ... Same with diferent id
```

In the activity y check to have the same password on the editText with this, i put one Toast to show me te variables vPassword and vCPassword and the Toast show this:

[image]

**The Activity Code**

```
vDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    vNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNombre);
    vPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    vCorreo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCorreo);
    vCPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmPassword);
    vRegistrarse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Registrarme);

    vRegistrarse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nombre = vNombre.getText().toString();
            password = vPassword.getText().toString();
            correo = vCorreo.getText().toString();
            cpassword = vCPassword.getText().toString();


            if(!nombre.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !correo.isEmpty() && vPassword.equals(vCPassword)){
                if(password.length() >= 6) {

                        registerUser();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La contraseña debe tener al menos 6 dígitos y ser igual", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alguno de los campos esta vacio"+vPassword+vCPassword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare edittext not it's values. So change your if condition

Change this :

```
vPassword.equals(vCPassword)
```

Into this :

```
password.equals(cpassword)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to change:

```
vPassword.equals(vCPassword)
```

to

```
password.equals(cpassword)
```

in your if condition